# How to insert a row with "autonumber" field (ID column) into Access Database/ C# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database

This is my first time working with DB.
I've decided to create a DB with two tables - "Team", "Player"
I want to add a new player to the "Player" table.
The "Player" table consists of the following columns: ID(autonumber), FirstName, LastName, TeamID

In order to do so, I've created three text boxes for the FirstName, LastName, TeamID
Note that I did not treat the "ID" since it's an autonumber and should be added automatically
The Button1_click should add the new row eventually.

Here's my code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch
        { }
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')");

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

        }
        catch
        { }
```

Comment: *Note that I did not treat the "ID" since it's an autonumber and should be added automatically* You seem to be telling us the answer. What is the question?

Comment: When asking a question you should always explicitly say what problem you are having with applicable error messages (if appropriate). There seems to have been a pretty good set of guesses in the answer as to what the question was but you shouldn't leave people needing to guess.

Comment: Empty catch blocks are evil. They prevent you from telling us what, and where, your problem is. BTW : if TeamID column is a number, TextBox3.Text should not be inside single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write an INSERT string that doesn't include the column names you should specify every column in the values. In your case you need to add

```
 string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, TeamID) VALUES ('" 
                  + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')");
```

However this code is wrong for another reason. Never write sql strings concatenating input text typed by the user. This will cause errors or, worse, lead to [Sql Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

```
   using(connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   { 
        connection.Open(); 
        string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, TeamID) " + 
                         "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, connection); 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", textBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", textBox3.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
```

There is another problem. If the TeamID field is a numeric field you need to convert the textbox3.text input in a numeric value to correctly use the AddWithValue method

```
        int teamID;
        if(!Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out teamID))
             throw new ArgumentException("Type a valid TeamID number, please!");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", teamID);
```

Comment: Good job on the parameterized version. I was too lazy to go confirm the right syntax. ;-) Do you not need the brackets around the field names though?

Answer (score 0):

If TeamID is a number, you don't need quotes around it.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('" + TbFirstName.Text + "','" + TbLastName.Text + "'," + TbTeamID.Text + ")");
```

Note: I renamed the textboxes to reduce ambiguity.

While this is probably your first pass at this, you should really sanitize your inputs. At the bare minimum create a function to replace single quotes with a double single quote.

```
protected string SanitizeSQL(string txt) {
   return txt.replace("'", "''");
}


OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('" + SanitizeSQL(TbFirstName.Text) + "','" + SanitizeSQL(TbLastName.Text) + "'," + SanitizeSQL(TbTeamID.Text) + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert command should specify the columns it's updating, so it should be:

```
INSERT INTO Player(FirstName,LastName,TeamID) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')"
```

Also note that concatenating text from user input directly into a query opens you up to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone
I did add a question guess somehow it dissapeared (I'm a noob here)